# How to typespec generics in Elixir

Tags: generics, types, erlang, elixir

I have an implementation of a Balanced Search Tree in elixir which serves as a key value store.

I have a method `from_list` which takes a list of key value tuples and returns a tree with them. Is there a way to use generics to typespec this the way I would do in a strongly typed language?

```
@spec from_list([{key_type, value_type}]) :: tree(key_type, value_type)
def from_list(list), do:
```

When I try this I get an error. Are there generics in Elixir? Or do I have to just make it a list of type {any, any}?

Comment: The `MapSet` module defines types that are somewhat like generics (see types of `difference` and `union`): https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/map_set.ex, but Dialyzer doesn't seem to be actually using that extra info while type checking.

Answer (score 8):

```
@spec from_list([{key_type, value_type}]) :: tree(key_type, value_type) when key_type: var, value_type: var
```

From [Typespecs — Elixir [latest]](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html):

> Guards can be used to restrict type variables given as arguments to the function.
>
> ```
> @spec function(arg) :: [arg] when arg: atom
> ```
>
> If you want to specify more than one variable, you separate them by a comma.
>
> ```
> @spec function(arg1, arg2) :: [arg1, arg2] when arg1: atom, arg2: integer
> ```
>
> Type variables with no restriction can also be defined using `var`.
>
> ```
> @spec function(arg) :: [arg] when arg: var
> ```